# MLP with TensorFlow Input Shape not Matching Output Shape

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to train a multilayer perceptron based on the Iris dataset using TensorFlow in Pycharm with Jupyter Notebook. Every time I run my code it fails on the model.fit() function and gives the following error.

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 3) are incompatible.
```

I've tried playing around with different values for the hyperparameters but there's obviously something I'm not getting. Any help/pointers that anyone could provide would be much appreciated.

Here's my data setup and preprocessing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# read iris data into pandas dataframe
iris = pd.read_csv("data/IRIS.csv", header=0)
# apply label to index column
iris.index.name = "id"

# create copy of iris dataframe in which to store normalised values and keep original dataframe for comparison later on
iris_unnormalized = iris
iris_normalized = iris.copy()

# isolate columns with numerical values
iris_num = iris.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
# find max value in each column
col_maxes = iris_num.max()
# find overall max value among all columns
iris_num_max = col_maxes.max()
# divide all numerical values by overall max value in order to normalize data to a value between 0 and 1
iris_num_norm = iris_num / iris_num_max

# reassign normalised values back to their corresponding columns
iris_normalized[iris_num_norm.columns] = iris_num_norm

# specify seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(1671)

training = iris_normalized.sample(frac = 0.8)
test = iris_normalized.drop(training.index)

# initialize the training input and output list
# same for testing set
X_train = []
Y_train = []
X_test = []
Y_test = []

# loop through the dataframe and separate inputs and outputs for training and testing
for index, row in training.iterrows():
    X_train.append([row['sepal length cm'], row['sepal width cm'], row['petal length cm'], row['petal width cm']])
    Y_train.append([row['species']])

for index, row in test.iterrows():
    X_test.append([row['sepal length cm'], row['sepal width cm'], row['petal length cm'], row['petal width cm']])
    Y_test.append([row['species']])

X_train = np.array(X_train).astype('float32')
Y_train = np.array(Y_train)

X_test = np.array(X_test).astype('float32')
Y_test = np.array(Y_test)

print(X_train.shape, "training samples")  # Output: (120, 4) training samples
print(X_test.shape, "test samples")       # Output: (30, 4) test samples
```

Here's where I try to create the neural network:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

NB_CLASSES = 3           # number of iris varieties
N_HIDDEN = 128
BATCH_SIZE = 10
VERBOSE = 1
VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.2  # how much of training set to hold for validation
EPOCHS = 200          

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.Dense(N_HIDDEN, input_shape=(10,4,), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, name="dense_layer1", activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Dense(N_HIDDEN, input_shape=(4,), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, name="dense_layer2", activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Dense(NB_CLASSES, input_shape=(4,), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, name="dense_layer3", activation="softmax"),
    ]
)

model.summary()

###################  model summary output: #####################
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_layer1 (Dense)         (10, 10, 128)             640       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_layer2 (Dense)         (10, 10, 128)             16512     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_layer3 (Dense)         (10, 10, 3)               387       
=================================================================
Total params: 17,539
Trainable params: 17,539
Non-trainable params: 0

# compiling the model
model.compile(optimizer='SGD', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

#train the model
model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
          epochs = EPOCHS,
          verbose = VERBOSE,
          validation_split = VALIDATION_SPLIT)
```

The data setup and normalization work fine but when I run the code to create the neural network I get the below error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8888/2571387568.py in <module>
     38 
     39 #train the model
---> 40 model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
     41           batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
     42           epochs = EPOCHS,

\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1182                 _r=1):
   1183               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1184               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1185               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1186                 context.async_wait()

\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    883 
    884       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 885         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    886 
    887       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    931       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    932       initializers = []
--> 933       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    934     finally:
    935       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    757     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
    758     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
--> 759         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    760             *args, **kwds))
    761 

\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3064       args, kwargs = None, None
   3065     with self._lock:
-> 3066       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3067     return graph_function
   3068 

\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3461 
   3462           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3463           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3464           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3465 

\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3296     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3297     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3298         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3299             self._name,
   3300             self._python_function,

\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes, acd_record_initial_resource_uses)
   1005         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
   1006 
-> 1007       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1008 
   1009       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    666         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    667         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 668           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    669         return out
    670 

\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    992           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    993             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 994               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    995             else:
    996               raise

ValueError: in user code:

\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:853 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:842 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1286 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2849 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3632 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:835 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
 \venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:788 train_step
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:201 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py:141 __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py:245 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py:1665 categorical_crossentropy
        return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py:4839 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py:1161 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 3) are incompatible
```

Comment: Did you maybe forget to one-hot encode your Y values? It seems to me like your Y values are currently encoded as [1, 0, 2, 1, 2, ...] instead of [[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], ...]. If this was the case, then there would be a mismatch because your training labels are one dimensional while your network output has three dimensions.

Comment: Additionally, you seem to have put a wrong shape value at your first layer in your network. You wrote "input_shape=(10,4,)", but the input shape that you give here should not include your batch dimension. The batch dimension is separately specified by writing "batch_size=BATCH_SIZE", just like you did. So the value you probably want to have there is "input_shape=(4,)"

Comment: No point in including code that comes *after* the error, as well as "introductions" ("new to ML and struggling") - both serve only as unnecessary clutter (edited out).

Comment: @MarcFelix It was the one-hot encoding, thank you so much!